# Trying to get property of non-object ErrorException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel and created a mini program using a bit of help of twitter bootstrap.

I'm trying to access this route:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create
```

And I get these **errors**:

> 2/2 ErrorException in 73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php line 4:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\alquirozlaravel\resources\views\show-solo.blade.php)

```
in 73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php line 4
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\storage\\framework\\views/73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'post' => null)) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\resources\\views/show-solo.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'post' => null)) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\public\\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

> 1/2 ErrorException in 73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php line 4:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

```
in 73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php line 4
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\storage\\framework\\views\\73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php', 4, array('__path' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\storage\\framework\\views/73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'post' => null), 'obLevel' => 1, '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'post' => null)) in 73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php line 4
at include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\storage\\framework\\views\\73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\storage\\framework\\views/73427cb411f683691ba00d0846f7eda3c61bff74.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'post' => null)) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\resources\\views/show-solo.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'post' => null)) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\alquirozlaravel\\public\\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Here are my **routes** at the moment:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@showForm');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@store');
```

My **Controllers**:
(PostController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $posts = Post::latest()->get();

        return view('index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function showById($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        return view('show-solo', compact('post'));
    }

    public function showForm()
    {
        return view('new-post');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'title' => 'required|min:2',
            'body' => 'required|min:10'
        ]);

        Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);

        return redirect('/posts');
    }
}
```

(CommentController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    // Convention to POST ADD
    public function store(Post $post)
    {
        Comment::create([
            'body' => request('body'),
            'post_id' => $post->id
        ]);

        // return back() works too
        return back();
    }
}
```

The **Blades** in question i think:
(show-solo.blade.php)

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
        <div class="blog-post">
            <h2>Post number: {{ $post->id }}</h2>

            <h2 class="blog-post-title">
                <a class="title-link" href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
            </h2>

            <!-- {{ $post->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }} -->
            <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }} by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>
            {{ $post->body }}

            <hr />

            @include('partials.error')

            @include('partials.post-comment')
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

(new-post.blade.php)

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
        <h1>Publish a Post<hr /></h1>

        <form method="POST" action="/posts">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="body">Body</label>
                <textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
            </div>

            @include('partials.error')
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

(master.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Blog Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/blog.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}">
</head>

<body>      
    @include('partials.nav')

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            @yield('content')

            @include('partials.sidebar')

        </div><!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    @include('partials.footer')

</body>
</html>
```

Here are my **models** if it helps:
(Post.php)

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

(Comment.php)

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Before the posts/create route works fine and now it won't. When I try to remove the route Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById'); the post/create route works properly again. What Am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `create` route is listed after the general `posts/{id}` route. Laravel handles every segment after the /posts/ as an id and ignores the "special" `create` route.

Swap those two lines like this:

```
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@showForm');
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById');
```

Furthermore I'd suggest you to use [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) which makes your life a bit easier with routing!

Comment: That worked, never realized that the placing of routes accordingly may affect routing behaviors. Thanks so much and I'll be reading that link.

Answer (score 2):

Change your route

From

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById');
```

To

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this one. But can I ask what does this specific line refer? ->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Comment: @JustinF It's mean validate your `id` segment must be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) and still have the same problem , you should check your database because something within the columns may be NULL.