# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to access the variable I passed from the controller inside the view. I created the controller using the command :

```
php artisan make:controller CompaniesController --resource
```

So I have all the resource methods for use.

> This is the route that I gave

```
Route::resource('/createcompany','CompaniesController' );
```

> This is the function inside my controller

```
public function show($id)
{
  $company = Company::find($id);
  return view('pages.admin.showcompany')->with('company', $company);
}
```

> Company has id and name as attributes
>
> This is my view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1>{{$company->name}} </h1>

@endsection
```

I looked up similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739449/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-errorexception-laravel), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420061/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-view-c-xampp-htdocs-enginepoker2-resourc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)) but they were not helpful.

Comment: Double check what `$company` actually contains with `dd($company);` before you return the view. Also make sure that the id you're using actually exists in the database.

Comment: Yeah the dd($company) returned null. Solved it.  Thank you ! @MagnusEriksson

Comment: For next time; Always start by doing some proper and basic debugging before posting a question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a beginner in laravel. Excuse me for this time! Sorry and thank you! @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No need to apologize. Just have that in mind for next time :-)

Comment: Sure, I will definitely do that  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the Company object like:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $company = Company::find($id);

    if( is_null($company) ){
         dd( "There's no company with the id=".$id);
    }

    return view('pages.admin.showcompany')->with('company', $company);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz for your intervention, yes you're right... updated

Comment: Congratulations @bohemianjock, you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it if any answer helps, if any answer from the posted here is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** For the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use `findOrFail()` method, It will automatically send you the model not found exception if not any model available.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $company = Company::findOrFail($id);

    return view('pages.admin.showcompany')->with('company', $company);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for show:

```
public function show(Company $company)
    {
        return view('pages.admin.showcompany',compact('company'));
    }
```